# Refresh page on mobile device, if signal found

Tags: javascript, html

I'm courius, if there is a way to check, when smartphone or tablet lost gsm signal. If this happens, can Javascript detect that situaltion, and refresh page, when signal will be again ?

Or, try to refresh page, for example with 10 sec interval, to check if signal is again good.

Thanks for any clue.